# CASE statment returning multiple rows for scalar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have the following code

```
  DECLARE @ProjectID INT
    DECLARE @getSLAPrjectID CURSOR
    SET @getSLAPrjectID = CURSOR FOR SELECT ProjectID FROM SLA

    OPEN @getSLAPrjectID

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getSLAPrjectID INTO @ProjectID
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

    BEGIN

    SET @ScheduleVariance = (select case when (DATEDIFF(day,PlannedStartDate,PlannedEndDate)=0) THEN 0 ELSE (DATEDIFF(day,ActualStartDate,ActualEndDate)-DATEDIFF(day,PlannedStartDate,PlannedEndDate))/CAST(DATEDIFF(day,PlannedStartDate,PlannedEndDate) as float) END from SLA)

    -- other piece of code that is working fine

    END

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getSLAPrjectID INTO @ProjectID

    END

    CLOSE @getSLAPrjectID
    DEALLOCATE @getSLAPrjectID

    --end
```

I AM GETTING THE FOLLOWING ERROR : Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

please let me know if there is any alternative to either CASE statement in this piece of code or alternative to the scalar variable .

Comment: How many rows are in the table `SLA`? Perhaps you either need a `DISTINCT` or a `WHERE` clause to filter it down to one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than 1 row in SLA. You can get around this by using `TOP 1` as long as you use `ORDER BY` to ensure the query is deterministic.

```
SELECT  TOP 1 @ScheduleVariance = CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(DAY, PlannedStartDate,PlannedEndDate) = 0) THEN 0 
                                ELSE (DATEDIFF(DAY, ActualStartDate, ActualEndDate) / CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY,PlannedStartDate, PlannedEndDate) AS FLOAT)) - 1 
                            END 
FROM    SLA
ORDER BY ProjectID
```

However, I suspect you are also missing a where clause from your query.

```
SELECT  @ScheduleVariance = CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(DAY, PlannedStartDate,PlannedEndDate) = 0) THEN 0 
                                ELSE (DATEDIFF(DAY, ActualStartDate, ActualEndDate) / CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY,PlannedStartDate, PlannedEndDate) AS FLOAT)) - 1 
                            END 
FROM    SLA
WHERE   ProjectID = @ProjectID
```

or

```
SET @ScheduleVariance = 
    (   SELECT  CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(day,PlannedStartDate,PlannedEndDate) = 0) THEN 0 
                    ELSE (DATEDIFF(day, ActualStartDate, ActualEndDate) / CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY,PlannedStartDate, PlannedEndDate) AS FLOAT)) - 1 
                END 
        FROM    SLA
        WHERE   ProjectID = @ProjectID
    )
```

Note, I've also tidied up your calculation, so changed

```
(x - y) / y
```

to

```
(x / y) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the where condition SLA.ProjectID = @ProjectID inside the subquery.

```
SET @ScheduleVariance = (select case when (DATEDIFF(day,PlannedStartDate,PlannedEndDate)=0) THEN 0 ELSE (DATEDIFF(day,ActualStartDate,ActualEndDate)-DATEDIFF(day,PlannedStartDate,PlannedEndDate))/CAST(DATEDIFF(day,PlannedStartDate,PlannedEndDate) as float) END from SLA where SLA.ProjectID = @ProjectID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it's because table SLA contains more than one row. To solve it, you should add a WHERE clause that narrows down the result to one row.

I strongly recommend **not** to use TOP 1, unless you're absolutely sure that the first row of your rowset (properly sorted) is the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly this line is returning more than one row:

```
SET @ScheduleVariance = (select case when (DATEDIFF(day,PlannedStartDate,PlannedEndDate)=0)
                                     THEN 0
                                     ELSE (DATEDIFF(day,ActualStartDate,ActualEndDate)-DATEDIFF(day,PlannedStartDate,PlannedEndDate))/CAST(DATEDIFF(day,PlannedStartDate,PlannedEndDate) as float)
                         END from SLA)
```

You need one of the following to get one row:  WHERE clause, aggregation function (WHERE ?), or TOP 1.